# Does strict aliasing prevent you from writing to a char array through a different type?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, strict-aliasing

My understanding is that strict aliasing in C++ is defined in [basic.lval 11](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11):

> (11) If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> - (11.1) the dynamic type of the object,
> - (11.2) a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - (11.3) a type similar (as defined in [conv.qual](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual)) to the dynamic type of the object,
> - (11.4) a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
> - (11.5) a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - (11.6) an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its elements or non-static data members (including, recursively, an element or non-static data member of a subaggregate or contained union),
> - (11.7) a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object,
> - (11.8) a `char`, `unsigned char`, or `std​::​byte` type.

By my reading, per 11.8, this is always legal, since the program accesses the stored value of `x` through a glvalue of type `unsigned char`:

```
int x = 0xdeadbeef;
auto y = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&x);
std::cout << y[1];
```

I am curious about using a pointer that aliases to an array of `unsigned char`:

```
alignas(int) unsigned char[4] x;
auto y = reinterpret_cast<int*>(x);
*y = 0xdeadbeef;
```

Is this a violation of strict aliasing? My reading is that it isn't, however I was just told on another thread that it is. Per basic.lval only, it seems to me that there is no UB, since the program does not attempt to access the stored value: it stores a new one without reading it, and so long as subsequent reads use `x`, then no violation occurs.

Comment: So, your argument is that writing to is not accessing?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, my possibly incorrect argument is that the stored value isn't being accessed because it's not retrieved. It's conceptually possible to have storage that hasn't been initialized to any object, and that dissociation seems to imply that you can hit storage without hitting an object.

Comment: SA says that compilers can't make aliasing assumptions regarding accesses through character glvalues and that would seem to imply that there can't exist an implementation of strict aliasing in which storing something over a character array will have aliasing issues should you read back from the character array.

Comment: @zneak: Ever since C89, the rules in the Standard have been predicated upon the assumption that compilers writers will have enough judgment to behave sensibly in cases where it's useful and where there's no good reason not to, even if the Standard doesn't "baby" them by explicitly describing all such cases.  Many parts of the type-access rules are non-transitive in ways that make sense if and only if one recognizes that there are some situations where objects may be accessed using lvalues of types other than those listed.

Comment: @zneak: There is no reason a quality compiler shouldn't support code which takes the address of a char[] once, converts it to void*, and then uses the storage as other types without ever making any further reference to the original array. A quality compiler that doesn't recognize an association between an int* and the original array might not recognize that actions on the int* could affect the original array, but if code never again refers to the original array directly, a sensible quality compiler should have no reason to care.

Comment: Even if you disable all type analysis, alias analysis, optimisations... an array might not be sufficiently aligned to do that.

Comment: @curiousguy, compared to all of these other things (type analysis, AA, optimizations) that you have essentially no control over, the alignment problem is exceptionally easy to take care of. I've edited the question for it.

Comment: @zneak "_exceptionally easy_" ... in *modern* C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About the definition of "access":

http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.access

> 3.1 access [defns.access]
>   ⟨execution-time action⟩ read or modify the value of an object

In other words, storing value is also "access". It is still UB.

Answer (score 2):

There are many constructs which invoke UB, but which quality compilers should process correctly anyway.  The use of character-typed storage to hold other types is among them.  Requirement that a constructor for a `char[]` yield a pointer to aligned storage wouldn't make sense otherwise.

The authors of the C89 did not think it necessary to fully describe every situation where a quality implementation suitable for any particular purpose would need to behave predictably.  The Rationale recognizes that implementations may be conforming while being of such low quality as to be essentially useless, and suggests that there was no perceived need to forbid implementations from behaving in ways that would impair their usefulness.  Every subsequent C or C++ Standard has inherited parts of C89 which were never intended to be fully complete, and none of them have fully completed those parts.

The Standard makes no distinction between

- actions which invoke UB but even the most obtuse compiler writer would recognize that they should behave predictably (e.g. `struct foo {int x;} s; s.x=1;`);
- actions which quality compilers suitable for various purposes should process predictably, but which low-quality compilers or high-quality compilers that are suitable only for other purposes, might not;
- actions which some compilers may handle predictably, but where such treatment should not be generally expected from any other compilers--even those targeting the same purposes (platforms, application fields, etc.).

Declaring a `char[]` with a particular alignment, using the named array once to capture its address (and never using the named array again), and employing it as raw storage that can hold other types, should fall into the first category above (especially since--as noted above--alignment guarantees wouldn't serve much purpose otherwise).  A compiler may not recognize any pointers' relationship to the original array, and might thus not realize that actions on such pointers could interact with a `char[]`(*), but if the array is never again used as a `char[]` the compiler would have no reason to care.

(*) For example, given

```
char foo[10];

int test(int *p)
{
  if (foo[1])
    *p = 1;
  return foo[1];
}
```

an implementation might cache and reuse the first value read from `foo[1]`, not recognizing that a write to `*p` might alter the underlying storage.  If the named lvalue `foo` is never used after the first time its address is taken, however, it wouldn't matter what assumptions the compiler might make about whether it would be safe to cache reads of lvalue `foo`, because *there wouldn't be any*.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment, but I'm pretty sure that I've convinced myself that the other answer is pretty much the right one. (1/?)

Comment: Your first example actually does have unpredictable side effects; padding remains uninitialized using this pattern, so you can leak information if you copy the struct contents over to someone else. There was a rash of those in the Windows and XNU kernels (and Linux too, almost certainly) last year. (2/?)

Comment: The issue lies in the fact that C++ wants you to "create" an object before you use it. Creating an object is merely a conceptual operation; it's the step that happens between getting a pointer to the location that you want to use, and using the placement new, for instance. It might not actually do anything, but it could, for instance if you came up with a runtime that did extended validation. (3/?)

Comment: Creating an object on top of another object is legal and it ends the lifetime of the previous object. That's what you rely on when you take an array of bytes and instantiate an object on it. Of course, the step of "creating" the object doesn't actually do anything on most compilers, and it's the omission that "reasonable" behavior relies on here. I'm fairly certain that it's always safe in practice, especially because SA rules prevent the compiler from making any assumptions about char array aliasing, but yeah. (4/4)

Comment: @zneak: If a struct contains padding, implementations are allowed to disturb it when accessing the preceding member, though relatively few avail themselves of that freedom.  On the other hand, many implementations generally document their storage layouts in sufficient detail that one can create structures without padding.  In such cases, I see no room for uncertainty.

Comment: As for "reasonableness", a simple principle would go a long way: someone writing a compiler that claims to be suitable for some platform and application field should make a bona fide effort to support the constructs and idioms employed by programmers targeting the platform and field when practical, without regard for whether the Standard.  The Standard allows conforming implementations to be of such poor quality as to be useless.  The fact that the Standard allows a conforming implementation to jump the rails does not imply that a quality implementation may do so.

Comment: read up about CVE-2017-13869 if you would like an example of leak through padding. (Or I guess, uninitialized union fields in this specific case?)

Comment: @zneak: If one uses types with padding, one needs to avoid exposing them to insecure channels.  I find it curious that people often malign `strncpy` for the fact that it "needlessly" clears the tail of the destination buffer, even though such action is often precisely the right thing to do if one is going to send out or persist the buffer containing the destination string.

Comment: @zneak: The question I wish the authors of gcc would answer is: "Do you think the authors of the Standard ever thought anyone would care whether they mandated that compilers must do things that compilers were already doing anyway?"  From the rationale, I think it's pretty clear that they didn't, and thus their failure to mandate a common behavior is no indication that compilers shouldn't be expected to uphold it.  For the authors of "clang", my question would be why the authors would be more interested in whether the Standard would allow poor-quality-but-conforming implementations...

Comment: ...to do something, than in whether such behavior would make a compiler more or less useful for various purposes.  The value of an optimizer is affected as much by the range of programs with which it may be safely employed, as by the level of performance boost it gives those programs.  There is an increasing divergence between the language Dennis Ritchie designed, and in which a lot of low-level code is written, and the language that the maintainers of gcc and clang want to process.